# How to "properly" read remote sshd server version with bash

Tags: bash, tcp, read

I'm trying to read remote SSHD server version with bash without installing an extra tool :

```
$ cat < /dev/tcp/x.y.z.t/22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 FreeBSD-20160310
^C
```

CTRL+C is needed, so I tried to read only one line but something strange happens in the output :

```
$ read version < /dev/tcp/x.y.z.t/22
$ echo "=> version = $version, DONE."
, DONE.ion = SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 FreeBSD-20160310
```

I just found out there is an `\r` character at the end of the `version` variable value :

```
$ printf "$version" | od -ct x1z
0000000   S   S   H   -   2   .   0   -   O   p   e   n   S   S   H   _
         53  53  48  2d  32  2e  30  2d  4f  70  65  6e  53  53  48  5f  >SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_<
0000020   7   .   2       F   r   e   e   B   S   D   -   2   0   1   6
         37  2e  32  20  46  72  65  65  42  53  44  2d  32  30  31  36  >7.2 FreeBSD-2016<
0000040   0   3   1   0  \r
         30  33  31  30  0d                                              >0310.<
0000045
```

How can I prevent the bash `read` builtin from reading the trailing `\r` character ?

Comment: If you can log in via ssh, do that and run `sshd -v`. At least for me, it produces a complaint, but then *prints the version* and a short usage text.

Comment: @sudodus No, I don't have a SSH access to that server.

Comment: You can filter the output from echo via `tr -d '\r'` which mean to delete carriage return from the stream of data.

Comment: @sudodus OK. I was hoping for a way to prevent the bash `read` builtin from reading the trailing `\r` character.

Comment: You can try with `read -r`, which may or may not help. See `help read`

Comment: @sudodus I already have but `read -r` does not remove the trailing `\r` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IFS` variable can be (locally!) modified to also include `\r`. This code probably needs more error checking on the arguments and perhaps some thought on how to handle timeouts or other such network issues.

```
function read-ssh-version {
   local IFS=$'\r\n'
   read version < /dev/tcp/"$1"/"$2"
   echo "$version"
}
```

Some minimal adhoc testing that the function works and that the global `IFS` variable hasn't been modified:

```
bash-5.1$ read-ssh-version 127.0.0.1 22 | od -c
0000000    S   S   H   -   2   .   0   -   O   p   e   n   S   S   H   _
0000020    9   .   0  \n
0000024
bash-5.1$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -c
0000000       \t  \n
0000003
```

(The `\r\n` sequence is generally mandatory for Internet protocols, and differs from the typical Unix `\n` newline sequence, but that's a different question... but that's why that pesky `\r` is there.)